# Using logging with basicConfig and RotatingFileHandler

Tags: python, logging

I'm trying to use `logging.basicConfig` to log everything and `logging.hanlers.RotatingFileHandler` to have a `maxBytes=1000000` and `backupCount=5`.
The problem is that when I use `RotatingFileHandler` it'll log some duplicate outputs as well.
I tried removing `basicConfig` and only using `RotatingFileHandler` but it didn't log every message I wanted.

example:

```
logging.basicConfig(format=f, datefmt=date, level=lvl, filename=file_name)
handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(file_name, maxBytes=1000000, backupCount=5)
logging.getLogger('').addHandler(handler)
```

I changed that to remove `basicConfig` by:

```
handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(file_name, maxBytes=1000000, backupCount=5)
handler.setFormatter(f)
handler.setLevel(lvl)
logging.getLogger('').addHandler(handler)
```

The above didn't work as `RotatingFileHandler` didn't log every message that I wanted. Why?

Comment: Could be a bug; you may need to manually create a minimum example (which may be hard) to actually demonstrate this issue. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975609/python-timedrotatingfilehandler-logs-are-missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logger that you get from `logging.getLogger('')` has its logging level set by default to `logging.WARNING`. You need to set the desired level on the logger itself as well as on each handler you associate with it to ensure you log the desired messages. Your second code snippet sets the level for the handler but not the logger.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.setLevel

Comment: thanks doing that seemed to have worked (formats different but I can probably fix that) but why do I have to set the level on both the logger and the handler?

Comment: A common pattern is to have multiple handlers on a single logger with different levels. For example you might want to print only ERROR level messages to the console, but include INFO or DEBUG information in your logfile. Other use cases may want to change the logging level for all log messages by just setting the level on the logger. I do question the decision to make WARNING the default level for loggers while INFO is the default level for handlers... that tends to make things confusing.

Answer (score 3):

The default level of the root logger is `logging.WARNING`. This causes messages which are less severe to be ignored (see [Logging Levels](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#levels)). In order for the root logger to delegate all messages, its level needs to be set to `logging.NOTSET`.

```
import logging
import logging.handlers

# Change root logger level from WARNING (default) to NOTSET in order for all messages to be delegated.
logging.getLogger('').setLevel(logging.NOTSET)

# Add file rotatin handler, with level DEBUG
rotatingHandler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(filename='rotating.log', maxBytes=1000, backupCount=5)
rotatingHandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
rotatingHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
logging.getLogger('').addHandler(rotatingHandler)

log = logging.getLogger("myApp." + __name__)

log.debug('Hello, debug message.')
log.info('Hello, info message.')
log.warning('Hello, warning message.')
log.error('Hello, error message.')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the basicConfig and RotatingFileHandler through  "**logging.Formatter**" , the below code snippet shows how to implement that. This will log all the messages and avoid duplicates.

```
import logging
import logging.handlers

#Set logger with required log level as base 
loggerInstance = logging.getLogger('name_of_logger')
loggerInstance.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Configure the handler with filePath,maxBytes and backupCount
# maxBytes - theMaxSizeOfLogFileInBytes
# backupCount - numberOFBackUpFiles to be created ex: logFile1,logFile2 etc (after log rotation)
handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(completeLogFilePathWithFileName,
                                               maxBytes=100000,
                                               backupCount=30)
#Specify the required format                                               
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(filename)s %(funcName)s %(lineno)d %(levelname)s %(message)s')
#Add formatter to handler
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
#Initialize logger instance with handler
loggerInstance.addHandler(handler)
```

Use various options in logger to log once the loggerInstance is created.

Ex:

```
loggerInstance.debug("your debug message") #for debug
loggerInstance.error("your error message") #for error
```

for detailed documentation follow below link:
[https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#rotatingfilehandle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#rotatingfilehandler)