# Change the logger one will get when asking for root

Tags: python, multithreading, logging, concurrent.futures

I'm using pythons logging utility for [logging](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) in multiple threads ([concurrent](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html)). Unlike many examples on this ([cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html), [another so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16929639/python-logging-from-multiple-threads)) I want each thread to log to its own file (keep the thread-logs separate). This works well by using a separate `FileHandler` for each logger (and by explicitly getting a named logger for each thread) as shown in the below example.

Now the problem arises that I'd like to call more generic packages from within each thread and also from other places in the code that produce their owns loggings. How do I ensure their loggings are captured in the file belonging to the thread that called it?

```
import logging
import concurrent.futures

def generic_function(xyz):
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.info("Very generic stuff")

def do_work(i):
    logger = logging.getLogger(f'logger{i}')
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    fh = logging.FileHandler(f'logging_{i}.log')
    logger.addHandler(fh)

    logger.info(f"BeeBaaBoo {i}")
    generic_function(123)

    return 

outps = []
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    for i in range(10):
        outp = executor.submit(do_work, i)
        outps.append(outp)

for outp in outps:
    if outp.exception() is not None:
        raise outp.exception()
```

I know I can pass around the logger instance or its name, but that would require me to make the generic package more specific. I can change the generic package to adapt better logging principles but don't want to require it to expect my threading business.

Maybe it's possible to change the logger one will get when asking for a new one?

Comment: I could see putting each *work item*'s logs in a separate file, but why would you want to segregate logs by *thread*? If you really want to do that, it should be the responsibility of the log `Handler` rather than requiring a separate `Logger` object for each thread.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question. One work thread calculates everything about a human protein, its binding site, its moleculary interaction field, its associated ligand bindings etc. The next thread does the same thing, for another protein. During these calculations there are all sorts of things that work and don't work, I'd like to keep a track of that per protein. If I send this all to the same file, output from different protein's will be all interleaved. Still think I shouldn't want this or do it differently? I'd like to hear,...

Comment: My point is that you don't need a separate `Logger` to get separate output. A `Logger` is a *source* of log messages; a `Handler` is what produces output. If you want to define a *context* for a series of log messages that are related (so that a `Handler` can do something different with them), you probably want to use a [`Filter` that reads from a thread-local variable](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-filters-to-impart-contextual-information).

Comment: Ah, that could be it! And the filter can be different for the same library depending on where it got called from?