# Intermittent PermissionError opening file in append mode in Python program

Tags: python, file

I have a Python program that opens a text file in append mode (think of it being something like a log file) and writes some new output to it before closing it. Occasionally, a `PermissionError` exception is raised at the line `with open(log_file_path, "a") as f`.

**NB** This question might look like a duplicate but all of the answers I have seen to similar questions talk about issues such as setting permissions on directories and suchlike. That does not apply here as this is something that happens *intermittently* (not every run and not at the same point when it does happen). Almost always, it happens at a point in a run after it has already been working for a while.

Another program (not Python BTW and not under my control) periodically reads the file. As this issue happens intermittently, my assumption is that there is some sort of file locking issue occurring caused by the other process opening the file for reading. If I place my file open statement inside a loop that retries a certain number of times, with a short sleep between each, the issue goes away. Problem solved - sort of - but it hardly seems satisfactory.

Two questions:

1. Does it seem plausible that this exception can arise in a Python program that opens a file for appending at the same time that another process is either opening it, or already has it open, for reading?
2. Is there a "correct" way to deal with this? I have found it surprisingly difficult to find any guidance. Surely it is quite a common scenario to want to read from files that are continuously being updated by another process and where the two programs are implemented independently (so no special protocol is possible).

**Edit**: clarifying a few points raised in comments.

1. This issue has only been seen on Windows.
2. Both applications are running under the same user account.
3. Only one process writes to the file. The other process only ever reads from it.
4. When I said "not under my control", the truth of the situation is that the other application is developed by a another team in a different part of the company working in a separate repository and on a separate development schedule. Practically, any sort of coordinated fix is not possible at the moment. However, I do know enough about the consuming code to know what it does. As stated above, it only reads the file.
5. The consuming application is a kind of integration hub that runs and collects output from numerous other applications like mine. Reading of log files from the different applications is typical of what it does, and so far there is no special infrastructure or protocol for coordinating this and as far as I am aware none has been needed.

Comment: "not under my control)": so is that process run by another user (either some sort of system user, or an actual user). Also, what OS are you using?

Comment: If you have multiple applications (regardless of the language they're written in) that may need to access a particular file concurrently then you need to arrange for such applications to cooperate. Imagine what would happen if two (or more) applications each wanted to append to the same file

Answer (score 1):

Diagnosis & fix options:

1. Write to a separate application-specific log file.  If you're explicitly supposed to merge the logs from the two (or more) different applications, write each log to a separate file, and have an additional process which merges their output into a file separate from all of the individual-process logs.
2. Check if your application is multithreaded.  If you're trying to log multiple messages at the same time, then the error makes sense.  If you're just tripping over other threads in your app, create a [shared Lock object or similar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#) to explicitly control hand-off between the threads.
3. Add a [check to see what the actual permissions are on the file just before / after the read](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-check-the-permissions-of-a-file-using-Python), and log the results to console or to a separate file - preferably with another log message saying whether the read actually succeeds. This *should* let you know if there's something unexpected happening with file permissions, like an unknown process which occasionally grabs control of the file before releasing it. Note, however, that there's a race condition between check-for-permissions and try-to-write-to-file, so the [usual Python "EAFP" mantra" is to not rely on that check](https://realpython.com/python-lbyl-vs-eafp/)
4. The option you've already described, putting the file-write inside a try-except block, with a loop that [occasionally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff) retries the write. If you want to get fancy, and need to maintain performance of your app despite the resource competition, you can write immediately to an [internal queue](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/asyncio-queue.html) and have a separate thread which occasionally tries to flush the queue to the log file, or blocks execution if the queue gets full. For large queues, this resembles option #1.
5. Depending on the results of #3, it may be the case that the other known process (or something else) is opening the file in "append mode", "r+", or some such, when it only needs "read mode" permission. If you have access to the other app's source code, you might be able to check for this and fix that code.

Which option you go for (or if you come up with some hybrid / modification of the above, or something from other answers) depends largely on your specific performance requirements and how much time you want to spend building the system.  To my knowledge, #4 is the most common solution, and parallel file *reads* should be safe - with errors only likely when you've got parallel *writes*... but that may vary by OS. Something like #4 is [already built into Python's "logging" module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16929639/ensuring-python-logging-in-multiple-threads-is-thread-safe)... so if what you're doing is sufficiently close to logging, just use `logging` directly and be done with it.

Comment: Thanks for a comprehensive reply. As mentioned in my updated question, I do have reasonable knowledge of the other program, it's just that, practically, I have to treat it as a black box that can't be modified easily. It only ever opens the file in read mode. My program never writes concurrently - there is no threading in the relevant code. I will add some diagnostic logging as suggested in #3. I think you confirm in #4 that my solution is not unreasonable. It is very intermittent so performance is not an issue. In practice logging lib is not really an option for my use case.