# Multiple requests Flask, Gunicorn , Nginx logging not working

Tags: python, logging, flask, gunicorn, flask-restful

I'm doing performance testing in my Flask application.

```
  ngnix -> gunicorn -> flask
```

Log files:

- access.log *OK*
- gunicorn.log *OK*
- api.log *Just shows 1 request*

I'm using ab testing tool. My requests are handled properly and logged properly in Flask log file in my Dev environment (MacOS 10.10.5).

```
ab -c 10 -n 10 -A username:password https://1.1.1.1:8443/api/1.0/echo/
```

When I move to production, (Ubuntu) I can't see all 10 requests being logged in Flask log file. I only see 1 in api log file. **ab** tool reports all requests are handled properly.

I do see 10 requests in Ngnix, Gunicorn, but not in Flask.

**gunicorn** start script (Supervisord)

```
GUNICORN_LOGFILE=/usr/local/src/imbue/application/imbue/log/gunicorn.log
NUM_WORKERS=8
TIMEOUT=60
WORKER_CONNECTIONS=2000
BACKLOG=1000
exec gunicorn api:api_app --bind 0.0.0.0:8081 --log-level=DEBUG --log-file=$GUNICORN_LOGFILE --workers $NUM_WORKERS --worker-connections=$WORKER_CONNECTIONS --backlog=$BACKLOG --timeout $TIMEOUT
```

**api** file:

```
from application.app import api_app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    api_app.run(debug=False, threaded=True)
```

**api_app** Flask application

```
# =========================================================
# API Logs
# =========================================================

log = logging_conf.LoggerManager().getLogger("___app___", logging_file=settings.api_logfile)

# =========================================================
# Flask Application imports and database
# =========================================================
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext import restful
from werkzeug.contrib.fixers import ProxyFix

# =========================================================
# Flask Main Application
# =========================================================

api_app = Flask(__name__)  # Flask Application
api_app.config.from_pyfile("../../../conf/settings.py")  # Flask configuration

imbue_api = restful.Api(api_app)  # Define API
db = Model.db.init_app(api_app)  # Initialize database

# =========================================================
# API Definition
# =========================================================

imbue_api.add_resource(ApiBase, settings.BASE_API_URL)
imbue_api.add_resource(Echo, '/api/1.0/echo/')
# =========================================================
# API Proxy WSGi for gunicorn
# =========================================================

api_app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(api_app.wsgi_app)
log.info('Initializing API >>>')
```

**api_main**

```
import logging

# =========================================================
# IMBUE imports
# =========================================================

from flask import current_app
from flask import jsonify, request, Response, url_for
from flask.ext import restful
from flask.ext.restful import Resource

# =========================================================
# API Controller
# =========================================================

api = restful.Api

# =========================================================
# API Logs
# =========================================================

log = logging_conf.LoggerManager().getLogger("___app___", logging_file=settings.api_logfile)

# =========================================================
# API Version information
# =========================================================

class Echo(Resource):
    @authenticator.requires_auth
    def get(self):
        """

        :return:
        """
        try:
            # =========================================================
            # GET API
            # =========================================================
            log.info(request.remote_addr + ' ' + request.__repr__())
            if request.headers['Content-Type'] == 'application/json':
                # =========================================================
                # Send API version information
                # =========================================================
                log.info('api() | GET | Version' + settings.api_version)
                response = json.dumps('version: ' + settings.api_version)
                resp = Response(response, status=200, mimetype='application/json')
                return resp
```

**Versions**

```
gunicorn==19.3.0
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-HTTPAuth==2.7.0
Flask-Limiter==0.9.3
Flask-Login==0.3.2
Flask-Mail==0.9.1
Flask-Migrate==1.6.0
Flask-OAuthlib==0.9.1
Flask-Principal==0.4.0
Flask-RateLimiter==0.2.0
Flask-RESTful==0.3.5
Flask-Restless==0.17.0
Flask-Script==2.0.5
Flask-Security==1.7.5
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.1
Flask-WTF==0.12
```

**logging_conf**

```
class Singleton(type):
    """

    """
    _instances = {}

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances.keys():
            cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]


class LoggerManager(object):
    """

    """
    __metaclass__ = Singleton

    _loggers = {}

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def getLogger(name='___app___', logging_file='imbued.log', **kwargs):
        """

        :param name:
        :param logging_file:
        :param kwargs:
        :return:
        """
        # Define timezone
        logging.basicConfig(filename=logging_file,
                            filemode='w+',
                            level=logging.INFO,
                            format='%(asctime)s.%(msecs).03d %(levelname)s %(message)s',
                            datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')

        if not name:
            return logging.getLogger()
        elif name not in LoggerManager._loggers.keys():
            LoggerManager._loggers[name] = logging.getLogger(str(name))
        return LoggerManager._loggers[name]
```

Comment: where `logging_conf` is comming?

Comment: Just updated it original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem happens when you declare `log` variable. The multiple threads of gunicorn calls multiple instances of `getLogger` and then overwrites your logfile. That doesn't happen when you use Werkzeug server with `threaded` param `app.run(threaded=True)`.

If you just need to log the requests you can use the param `--access-logfile REQUEST_LOG_FILE` on gunicorn start script

```
GUNICORN_LOGFILE=/usr/local/src/imbue/application/imbue/log/gunicorn.log
NUM_WORKERS=8
TIMEOUT=60
WORKER_CONNECTIONS=2000
BACKLOG=1000
REQUEST_LOG_FILE=./request-log-file.log
exec gunicorn api:api_app --bind 0.0.0.0:8081 --log-level=DEBUG --log-file=$GUNICORN_LOGFILE --workers $NUM_WORKERS --worker-connections=$WORKER_CONNECTIONS --backlog=$BACKLOG --timeout $TIMEOUT --access-logfile REQUEST_LOG_FILE
```

See more on about loggin on [documentation](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/0.17.2/configure.html#logging).

**Warning: PROBABLY NOT SAFE**

As a simple workaround, you can change the basicConfig method inside getLogger to, instead of overwrite the file, append to an existing file. That is not safe, multiple threads changing the same file can leads to unexpected results.

```
logging.basicConfig(filename=logging_file,
                        filemode='w+', # Open, read and truncate the file.
                        level=logging.INFO,
                        format='%(asctime)s.%(msecs).03d %(levelname)s %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

to

```
logging.basicConfig(filename=logging_file,
                        filemode='a+', # Open, read and append to a file.
                        level=logging.INFO,
                        format='%(asctime)s.%(msecs).03d %(levelname)s %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

**EDIT 1**

Apparently [logging is thread safe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2973911/4338325) but I'm not sure if that will be extended for gunicorn workers...